# vue cli import scss from node_modules with alias

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli, vue-cli-4

How i can resolve nested imports inside node_modules package with aliases? I have an npm package. And in my vue cli project i have import from npm package: `@import ~npmPackage/src/theme.scss`. But theme.scss use another import inside: `@import @/var.scss`; Then i try to serve my project with vue cli its broken. vue cli cant find file with alias. If i change alias to relative path via `../` instead `@/` its fine... How to resolve it? Ps. i use vue cli 4. Thx a lot for answers:)